# Nodes not in Shader Editor

Tags: shaders

I am editing a leaf in shader editor, Nodes are not visible not even a material editor. How to create the nodes, or make them appear?

Answer (score 1):

Without any screenshot it is difficult to tell what's going on. Here are some tips:

**You don't have the shader panel visible:**

You can split any area and choose what kind of editor to show.
You can create a new Workspace based on templates (click on the `+` button next to the top tabs and choose *General > Shading*.

**You don't have any nodes**

Select your mesh and click on the `New` button from the [`Shader Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor.html). It's also possible that there are some nodes but are not in the actual view. So move the mouse on the *Shader Editor*, select all nodes by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and press dot key <kbd>NumPad .</kbd> to center the view on selected nodes (otherwise you can zoom out till you see something)

Here a video showing how to split an area:
https://i.imgur.com/I9lYQYM.mp4