# Why are shader nodes not showing up?

Tags: node-editor

I applied a texture on this object but later when I checked to see the *Shader Editor*, the nodes were gone.

[image]

I downloaded a material file from [ambientcg.com](https://ambientcg.com/) and plugged it into the *Principled BDSF* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>＋<kbd>Shift</kbd>＋<kbd>T</kbd> (this is what I learned from a tutorial video and I don't exactly know how the settings work)

Also, the default nodes *Principled BDSF* and *Material Output* don't show up when I create a new material in the *Shader Editor*.

Comment: have you tried zooming out, maybe its out of visible view

Comment: im so stupid it was at the point way too far from where I was looking at... thank you!

Comment: no prob! i always encounter this problem XD

Comment: You don't have to zoom out and search for the nodes, go inside the editor window and press A to select all, then Numpad "." to center on selected objects. Maybe you should try it too, @HarryMcKenzie if you always encounter this problem ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hey thank you Gordon! i think i remember i did that before i forgot thanks for reminding us :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodes not in Shader Editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179253/nodes-not-in-shader-editor)